# Unable to connect to docker on gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to make e2e tests on gitlab CI using a tests inside a docker container.

I Have the following docker-compose that I use to perform my tests :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '${NODE_PORT}:${NODE_PORT}'
    env_file:
      - ./.env-ci
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: 
      - prp_db
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./database
    container_name: pgsql
    env_file:
      - ./.env-ci
    volumes:
      - ./database/schema/base.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0.schema.sql
      - ./database/schema/tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.tables.sql
      - ./database/fixtures/basics.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.basics.sql
      - ./database/fixtures/relations.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3.relations.sql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

And the following gitlab-ci file

```
image: docker/compose:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''

before_script:
  - docker version
  - docker-compose version
variables:
  NODE_PORT: '3000'
  DB_HOST: 'host.docker.internal'
  DB_PORT: '5432'
  DB_USERNAME: 'postgres'
  DB_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
  DB_DATABASE: 'prpp'
  NODE_HOST: 'host.docker.internal'
  POSTGRES_DB: prpp
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.ci.yml build
    - docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.ci.yml up --exit-code-from api
  # test:
#   stage: test
#   cache: {}
```

I have several e2e tests that uses the supertest library. So I launch the unit tests and then integration tests :

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml up --exit-code-from api
```

This works fine, however when I see the build on gitlab. It appears that the nodejs server is not able to connect to the databse :

```
console.error
 api_1  |     { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal host.docker.internal:5432
 api_1  |         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
 api_1  |       errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
 api_1  |       code: 'ENOTFOUND',
 api_1  |       syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
 api_1  |       hostname: 'host.docker.internal',
 api_1  |       host: 'host.docker.internal',
 api_1  |       port: 5432 }
 api_1  | 
 api_1  |       26 |       });
 api_1  |       27 |     } catch (err) {
 api_1  |     > 28 |       console.error(err);
```

It's wierd because I have the same env variables as my .env-ci file :

```
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=prpp
DB_DATABASE=prpp
NODE_HOST=0.0.0.0
NODE_PORT=3000
```

Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks I figured out where the problem came from, it was from the host variables. You need to use make the DNS work from docker. This is my new env file :

```
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=prpp
DB_DATABASE=prpp
NODE_HOST=api
NODE_PORT=3000
DB_HOST=db
```

And the docker-compose ci :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
      context: ./
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - ./.env-ci
    networks:
      - main
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: 
      - prp_db
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./database
    container_name: pgsql
    env_file:
      - ./.env-ci
    volumes:
      - ./database/schema/base.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0.schema.sql
      - ./database/schema/tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.tables.sql
      - ./database/fixtures/basics.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.basics.sql
      - ./database/fixtures/relations.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3.relations.sql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - main
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
```

And the gitlab-ci remains the same :)

Happy coding